# Carregando os dados da Grid com CheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, loop, checkbox, telerik

Estou criando um formulário para realizar um cadastro de uma licença de um produto.

Este formulário serve para registrar qual solução um cliente possui.

No formulário para adicionar um produto basta você selecionar **produto** e o **cliente**.

Estou com dificuldade para elaborar a lógica do carregamento do formulario que deixe marcado "`checked`" os produtos que este cliente já possui.

Minha ideia inicial e fazer duas consultas que retornem um `DataTable`, a primeira consulta os produtos existentes, a segunda traz os produtos que o cliente possui .

**Primeira Consulta**

```
SELECT id, nome
FROM   produto
```

**Segunda Consulta**

```
SELECT produto_id
FROM licenca
JOIN produto on produto_id = produto.id
join pessoa on pessoa.id   = cliente_id
where cliente_id           = @id
```

Assim no carregamento ele durante loop vai fazer a comparação deixando marcado os que ele já possui .

```
foreach (DataRow row in ProdutosCLiente.Rows)
                {
                    int id = (int)row["produto_id"];
                    GridProduto.Rows[id].Cells[0].Value = CheckState.Checked;
                }
```

Alguém pode me dizer qual seria maneira correta de referenciar os valores que vão estar preenchidos? Estou com dificuldade para fazer a referencia durante o `loop`.

Comment: Você tem como postar uma base de seu model Produto e Cliente? No Datagrid só vão os dados do produto, certo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta mostrando a SQL de consulta , na grid são exibidos apenas os nomes da solução. Primeiro o usuário  seleciona o cliente define a data inicial e final da licença e depois seleciona o produto.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha resposta, editei a mesma mostrando uma forma que você pode fazer o que precisa com apenas uma consulta, sem utilizar loops e afins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando algumas propriedades do `Telerik` :

```
 private void radMultiColumnComboBoxPessoa_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Finaliza algum editor em aberto - Grid
                GridProduto.GridViewElement.EditorManager.EndEdit();

                //Inicia atualização - Grid
                GridProduto.TableElement.ViewTemplate.BeginUpdate();

                //Verifica se a pessoa foi selecionada
                if (radMultiColumnComboBoxPessoa.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                {
                    //Obtem a id do cliente selecionado 
                    int Cliente_id = (int)radMultiColumnComboBoxPessoa.EditorControl.Rows[radMultiColumnComboBoxPessoa.SelectedIndex].Cells["id"].Value;

                    //Armazena os produtos que o cliente possui
                    DataTable dataTableLicenca = Negocio.Licenca.Listar(Cliente_id);

                    var produto_ids = (from row in dataTableLicenca.AsEnumerable()
                                       select (int)row.GetValue("produto_id"));

                    foreach (var row in GridProduto.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row is GridViewDataRowInfo)
                        {
                            //Produto
                            int produto_id = (int)((System.Data.DataRowView)(row.DataBoundItem)).Row.GetValue("id");

                            //Valor a ser definido            
                            bool valueState = produto_ids.Contains(produto_id) ? true : false;

                            //Atualiza valor
                            row.Cells[0].Value = valueState;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var row in GridProduto.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row is GridViewDataRowInfo)
                        {
                            //Atualiza valor
                            row.Cells[0].Value = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade `Rows` do GridView é um array contendo as linhas do mesmo, o acesso a esse array é pelo índice da linha, e não pelo id do produto como você está fazendo.
Para fazer o que você quer vai ser preciso um loop dentro de outro loop, como por exemplo:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ProdutosCLiente.Rows)
{
     int id = (int)row["produto_id"];
     foreach (DataRow rowGrid in GridProduto.Rows)
     {
         if (id == int.Parse(rowGrid.Cells[(Aqui vai o índice da coluna contendo o id do produto)].Value))
         {
             rowGrid.Cells[0].Value = CheckState.Checked;
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

@Edit:

Uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso é utilizando apenas uma consulta para popular o grid, trazendo uma coluna que represente se o usuário tem o produto ou não.
Primeiro, no campo Checkbox do teu grid, é preciso colocar o seguinte:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="id" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("PossuiProduto")) %>' />
```

E então você modifica o select para retornar essa coluna utilizando um `CASE`

```
SELECT produto.id, produto.nome, CASE WHEN licenca.cliente_id IS NULL THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS PossuiProduto
FROM produto
LEFT JOIN licenca on licenca.produto_id = produto.id
where (licenca.cliente_id = @id OR licenca.cliente_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Marciano consegui resolver , tive que contatar meu superior por que tive que usar algumas propriedades do telerik , logo irei postar a resposta , muito obrigado pela ajuda !